# Connect to facebook from Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, authentication, comments

I want to click a button in my flash application, log in to facebook, leave a comment on wall and sign out. I try to figure it out but it seems complicated. Does anyone have an example or any sample code for this easy functionality?

Comment: Good question! Been looking into this myself..

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you have mentioned actionscript3. This is the [AS3 SDK for Facebook](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html)

On a side note, you might find [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/facebook_architecture_overview.html) quite useful

Comment: Thanks Eknath .. it was useful for basics and functionality .All I need, is a sample or example here which works in Flash.. Anyway, thanks ..  :) ,,

Answer (score 1):

BigSpaceship released a bunch of classes, one of them dealing with Actionscript and connecting to Facebook. Take a gander at their overview page http://www.bigspaceship.com/blog/labs/bss-classes-flash-and-the-fb-graph/ and see if it's something that works for your idea (it seems like it would).

Comment: They have a sample on "Forging ahead with Open Graph" which works but my problem is, I can`t find a way to get "access_token" ! .. it is not easy thing to do .. do you know how to get that?

Answer (score 1):

As said in previous answers, you can just use the graph api to connect to facebook. Below is a sample of how to start up your connection with facebook and how to get your access_token (It is used here to post to your wall).

```
public function FBConnect():void
{   
    //Set applicationid
    _applicationID = "YourID";

    //Set permissions to ask for
    _extendedPermissions = {perms:"read_stream, publish_stream, user_about_me, read_friendlists, user_photos"};

    //Initialize facebook
    Facebook.init(_applicationID);
}

public function post(message:String):void
{
    var _params:Object = new Object();

    _params.access_token = Facebook.getSession().accessToken;
    _params.message = message;

    Facebook.api("/" + _user + "/feed", messagePosted, _params, "POST");
}
```

This should do the trick :)